# Multiple Keystrokes

Tags: c#, keystroke

I've been trying to figure out how to get multiple key strokes with a single command. The goal is to have an effect like:

```
SendKeys.Send({"TAB"}{"TAB"}{"ENTER"}{"TAB"}{"ENTER"}{"TAB"}{"ENTER"});
```

I've been able to get two key strokes to work such as

```
SendKeys.Send(^{"TAB"})
```

However this is press and hold control + press tab. The goal I want is not to hold down a key then press, but to have the button press register multiple times. Thank You!

Comment: You should show what code you have written.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

SendKeys supports sending multiple keys. Why are you using incorrect syntax there? It should really be like:

```
SendKeys.Send("{TAB}{TAB}{ENTER}{TAB}{ENTER}{TAB}{ENTER}");
```

Answer (score 0):

Try using SendWait instead

SendKeys.SendWait("{TAB}{TAB}{ENTER}{TAB}");

This will ensure each keystroke is processed first before sending the next and seems to have the desired effect